# SQL Return 1 or distinct values from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

My goal is to get the customer balance report but I am stuck in my query 
where I can get the doc type of a certain column. I have my query

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY DR.id ) AS 'NO.' ,          
CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), CAST(DR.doc_date AS DATE), 100) AS 'DOC DATE',
SR.net_total,
SR.dell_col_charge,
SR.CDW,
sp.amount
FROM 
[dbo].[doc_customer]                DC
LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[doc_rent]            DR ON DR.doc_sourced_customer_id = DC.id
LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[slip_rent]           SR ON SR.doc_sourced_doc_rent_id = DR.id
LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[slip_rent_payment]   SP ON SP.doc_sourced_rent_id     = DR.id
```

as u can see in my query it returning the net total, charge, cdw, and amount
but my goal is to show them in 1 column in a different rows. u can see on the image I attached that's my goal of my query.

[image]

anyone have the idea ? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use `apply` for unpivoting:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY DR.id ) AS [NO.] ,          
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), CAST(DR.doc_date AS DATE), 100) AS [DOC DATE],
       v.*
FROM [dbo].[doc_customer] DC LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[doc_rent] DR
     ON DR.doc_sourced_customer_id = DC.id LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[slip_rent] SR
     ON SR.doc_sourced_doc_rent_id = DR.id LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[slip_rent_payment] SP
     ON SP.doc_sourced_rent_id = DR.id OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES ('net_total', SR.net_total),
             ('dell_col_charge', SR.dell_col_charge),
             ('CDW', SR.CDW),
             ('amount', sp.amount)
     ) v(which, val);
```

Comment: Thanks !  I have now the idea. But can I ask something why it's returning 
string like this "----" below of the name of the columns ? I'm unfamiliar with that.

Comment: That is how the application you are using for querying works.  SQL Server Management Studio does this when you put the results in text mode rather than in a grid.